# vue typescript with type assertions valid compile in jest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I have setup unit tests on my current Vue 2 project with typescript, and I have a lot of type assertions on my syntax, this is the example for my component

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper-note">
    <span>
      <icon-warning-circle />
    </span>
    <span>
      {{ str }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import IconWarningCircle from '@/app/ui/assets/icon_warning_circle.vue'

@Component({
  name: 'Note',
  components: {
    IconWarningCircle,
  },
})
export default class Modal extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: 'give me a note' }) private text!: string

  get str(): string {
    return <string>this.text
  }
}
</script>
```

when i have unit test file like this `__test__/index.spec.ts`

```
import { Wrapper, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Note from '@/app/ui/components/Note/Note.vue'

describe('Note Component', () => {
  let wrapper: Wrapper<Note, Element>

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Note)
  })

  it.only('should be rendered', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

the function `str()` is compile to jsx , and it said

```
Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <string>
```

but after i changed the `str()` like this

```
  get str(): string {
    return this.text as string
  }
```

it would be valid and my unit test passed,

is that any issue that i must config ??

here is my jest config

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json', 'vue'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: ['node', 'node-addons'],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/app/ui/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/ui/components/$1',
    '^@/app/ui/assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/ui/assets/$1',
    '^@/app/ui/views/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/ui/views/$1',
    '^@/app/ui/controllers/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/ui/controllers/$1',
    '^@/domain/entities/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/domain/entities/$1',
    '^@/app/infrastructures/misc/Utils':
      '<rootDir>/src/app/infrastructures/misc/Utils',
    '^@/app/infrastructures/misc/Constants/(.*)$':
      '<rootDir>/src/app/infrastructures/misc/Constants/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  // transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!tsyringe)'],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage', // check your coverage by UI on folder /coverage
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 90,
    },
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
}
```

i have tried install plugin `@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx` and `@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript` set it on `babel.config.js` still doesnt work :(

any help guys? been stucks for all day for this

// tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "./node_modules/user-agent-data-types",
      "@types/jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "__tests__/*.spec.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx', '@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript'],
}
```

Comment: The error means that Babel or TS JSX transform was applied while it shouldn't. You mentioned babel.config.js but didn't post it, it's relevant, same for tsconfig. TS `as` syntax was used to avoid clashing with JSX, you can just stick to it

Comment: @EstusFlask i have updated for babel config and tsconfig, thank u

Comment: There shouldn't be plugin-syntax-jsx. Does removing it affect anything?. Any way, replacing type assertions with "as" would be a preferable fix.